# If condition in shell script fails

Tags: bash, shell

I would like to what is the issue in this script , why this if condition is getting passed
i see that HI is printed , but type = A this if condition should not pass

```
[omega@ctsedgenode 1.1.11-SNAPSHOT_V12]$ type="A"
[omega@ctsedgenode 1.1.11-SNAPSHOT_V12]$  if [[ $type -eq "C" || $type -eq "D" ]]; then  echo 
"HI" ; fi
HI
[omega@ctsedgenode 1.1.11-SNAPSHOT_V12]$
```

Comment: `-eq` is for numbers, `=` or `==` is for strings (in bash this includes patterns).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this instead:

```
if [[ $type == "C" || $type == "D" ]]; then  echo "HI" ; fi
```